# Restricted profiles settings not being remembered

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean, restricted-profiles

I have followed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdUcANNm72o and set up settings for my app.

I have 10 Booleans that appear. This can be set and when in the profile called.

However they are not ticked/unticked then the owner goes back into the settings, they have reverted back to default.

1/ Is the system meant to know which user has which settings already selected or am I meant to tick or un tick in the GetRestrictionsReceiver. If I am, how am I meant to see each users settings as the

```
       Bundle restrictionsBundle = ((UserManager) getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE)).getApplicationRestrictions(getPackageName());
        restrictionsBundle.getBoolean("....
```

is for when the user is logged on!?

2/ Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1: Why did someone down-vote without comment? Didn't seem like a bad question.

Comment: @jacknad Thanks, that winds me up. You have a legit question and someone just say negative. anyway I solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that you need to add some code when generating the RestrictionEntry

Though I will update so that people don't have to hunt...

In your receiver call

```
        final Bundle oldRestrictions = intent.getBundleExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RESTRICTIONS_BUNDLE);
```

then when creating the entry reference it.

e.g.

```
RestrictionEntry myEntry = new RestrictionEntry(KEY, oldRestrictions.getBoolean(KEY, false)); 
myEntry.setType(RestrictionEntry.TYPE_BOOLEAN);
myEntry.setTitle("KEY TITLE");
newEntries.add(myEntry);
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the missing piece I was searching... :)