# How to detect restricted profile in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Android 4.3 provides the facility of restricted profile. so if user is on restricted profile then apps gets crashed on it and its works on normal mode.**is there any way to detect that user is in restricted mode**.
please tell me if anyone knows.

Comment: Check for the allowed permissions.

Comment: Apps do not normally "get crashed" when run in a restricted profile. Perhaps you should consider asking a fresh StackOverflow question, where you provide the code and stack trace for your crash, and seek advice on how to address that problem.

Comment: you can refer to my answer here.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855932/how-to-manage-restricted-profiles-in-android-app/30591360#30591360][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855932/how-to-manage-restricted-profiles-in-android-app/30591360#30591360