# How to detect a restricted profile

Tags: android, restricted-profiles

Background:
I'm currently developing an app which save user settings in "setting.cnfg" file. The file is original saved in internal storage /data/data/package_name. The Kitkat tablet Restricted Profile nolonger give me permission to write/read in that directory (non-rooted device), so I have to move the setting file to external storage.
But I still want other normal user to save file in the internal storage.

Question:
Is there any methood to detect a user is Restricted Profile or detect a user have permission to access internal storage at runtime?

edit:
I'm using native c++ and NDK to access file. But it may be not the problem.

Comment: Are you getting any error while writing file to Internal storage, as I am able to write to it in 4.4.2 ??

Comment: I can not access file while using restricted profile. I'm using fopen and it return NULL.

Comment: you need to change the Path

Comment: Yes. I changed the path and it worked. But I wana check user type to get proper behavior at runtime.

Comment: then please check the Android version at run time and code accordingly

Comment: try [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17857087/2591002)